# How to remove Wordpress images sizes from filename inside an HTML attribute?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm using the following code to remove the sizes added by Wordpress to medias' filenames.

```php
function replace_content($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/-([^-]*(\d+)x(\d+)\. ((?:png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp)))"/', '.${4}"', $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

How to change the regex to apply it only to the href attribute value?

Answer (score 0):

Folowing regex with preg_replace() function

```
$replaced_content = preg_replace( '#<img[^>]*?src[\s]?=[\s]?[\'"]?([^\'">]*?(https|http|\/\/)[^\'">]*?(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp))[^\'" >]*?)[\'" ][^>]*?>#',
                                  '<img src="$1">', $content );
```

cleans this awful img tag

```
<img ttl='Ren src = https://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/rename-on-save.png' alt="Rena width=520" height="344" wp-image-25391">
```

to this clean and nice code

```
<img src="https://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/rename-on-save.png">
```